# Does fileobj.flush() guarantee os.stat() to be updated?

Tags: python, file-io, stat

I'm opening a file and writing to it. After flushing, will `os.stat(file)` guarantee to have the correct size, or do I need to `os.fsync()`?

`os.fsync()` guarantees flushing the internal operating systems' buffers but incurs a large overhead.
If I don't wish to use it,  can I count on the major operating system' `stat()` to take the buffers into account?

A quick test showed promising results but I'm not sure if it's reproducible:

```
>>> import tempfile
>>> import os
>>> f = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
>>> os.stat(f.fileno()).st_size
0
>>> f.write(b"abc")
3
>>> f.flush()
>>> os.stat(f.fileno()).st_size
3
```

Comment: Take note that the exact semantics will depend on the operating system and filesystem. Is this for a local filesystem on a common OS, such as Windows, Linux or MacOS?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I wonder if there is at least a posix guarantee for that. I don't mind about non-common OSes. Windows, Linux, and MacOS are a good rule of thumb :-)